# Limited currency regex

Tags: java, regex, currency

I have found a lot of good currency regular expressions that get very close to what I need.  Alas, I am no regex guru and can't seem to edit my current regex to meet requirements.

I need to limit the valid inputs to the format of 'xxx,xxx.xx'.  The max allowed amount needs to be '999,999.99' with commas optional.  I've been using this regex until now:

`^([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9]+))(.[0-9]{2})?$`

It has been working great except for not being able to make the upper limit '999,999.99'.  Thanks for the help!

---

### Update

---

I've been tinkering and I've managed to come up with this:

`/^(?:([0-9]{3}?,?)?[0-9]{3}(?:\.[0-9]?[0-9]?)?)$/`

Still testing to see if it works.  [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) isn't passing it with any of the Strings I try, but I'll be going through my app and manually testing.

Comment: What is the min amount? `000,000,00` or `0,0,00`, or maybe something else?

Comment: @Pshemo I think minimum amount would be `0.00`, Thats just guess from `|` part

Comment: Minimum amount would be 0.  There's no requirement for having a value of `0` formatted as `0.00`

Comment: Are forms mentioned earlier also acceptable?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

burning_LEGION's answer authorizes some cases I think you probably don't want:
 - 999,9
 - 9.

I'll assume you want those conditions fulfilled:
 - if there is a comma, there are 3 numbers after
 - if there is a point, there are 2 numbers after

```
^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh yes, very true.  Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

use this regex `^\d{1,3}(,?\d{1,3}){0,1}(\.\d{0,2})?$`

Comment: +1 and in Java you need to escape \ in String so OP will need to replace \d with \\d.